# Abrir desde mi sitio un sitio externo (wordpress) y pasarle un archivo mediante http POST

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, http-post

Tengo un sitio desarrollado por mi en Angular 9. El mismo contiene una lista de archivos, con la url de cada uno, y necesito que al seleccionar un archivo, se abra el sitio de mi cliente (en la misma pestaña o en otra), que está hecho en Wordpress, y se cargue el archivo en un plugin que acepta http POST.

He intentado descargar el archivo desde mi proyecto y enviarlo mediante POST al sitio en una nueva ventana, pero no obtuve resultados. Las opciones que se me ocurren son:

- Descargar el archivo en mi proyecto y enviarlo mediante http
- Enviar la url mediante http al sitio wordpress, y modificar el código de este sitio para que reciba la url y descargue el archivo. Esto último no sé cómo hacerlo, por lo que necesito saber si realmente es realmente posible.

Este es el código que intenté:

```
getFile() {

    this.loadingFile = true;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', [URL del archivo], true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onprogress = function(e) {

        this.fileProgress = (e.loaded * 100) / e.total;
    }.bind(this);

    var self = this;

    xhr.onload = function(e) {

        if (this.status == 200) {

            const blob = this.response;

            self.postBlobToURL([URL del sitio externo], blob);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}


postBlobToURL(url: string, data: Blob) {

    let theWindow = window.open(url, 'TheWindow');

    var form = theWindow.document.createElement("form");
    form.action = [URL del plugin];
    form.method = 'POST';
    form.target = "TheWindow";

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.name = 'attribute_pa_p3d_model';
    input.type = 'file';
    input.files = this.fileListItem([new File([data], 'model.stl')]);
    form.appendChild(input);

    form.style.display = 'none';
    theWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}


fileListItem(a) {
    a = [].slice.call(Array.isArray(a) ? a : arguments)
    for (var c, b = c = a.length, d = !0; b-- && d;) d = a[b] instanceof File
    if (!d) throw new TypeError("expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects")
    for (b = (new ClipboardEvent("")).clipboardData || new DataTransfer; c--;) b.items.add(a[c])
    return b.files
}
```

Agradezco cualquier idea o sugerencia.

Comment: Comparte el codigo que hayas intentado para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ahí compartí el código

Comment: verifica que el plugin tenga un endpoint en el api rest de wordpress, seguramente puedas enviar el post directamente desde angular ( es woocommerce? attribute_pa suena a product attribute )